# Retrieve DataStax Session from CassandraOperations

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Spring Boot Data Cassandra has removed the ability to retrieve a `com.datastax.driver.core.Session` from `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations`. I'm trying to rectify old code that has these usages. Is there a simply way to retrieving the cassandra session? I'm looking for a way to create a prepared statement from an `Insert`, with only access to an instance of `CassandraOperations`, e.g.

`cassandraOperations.getSession().prepare(insert);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've removed `getSession()` from `CassandraOperations` because of two reasons:

- Interface split into `CassandraOperations` and `CqlOperations`. `CassandraTemplate` (which implements `CassandraOperations`) now uses `CqlOperations` as lower-level API.
- We introduced `SessionFactory` to be able to route CQL calls into various Cassandra `Session`s. CQL execution obtains a session from the configured `SessionFactory`. A session is considered valid during the execute call as the next command could be executed on a different session.

You can still obtain a `Session`. Either call:

```
CqlTemplate cqlTemplate = (CqlTemplate) cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations();
cqlTemplate.getSession();
```

or obtain `Session` through Spring's context (autowiring, lookup via `context.getBean(Session.class)`, …).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!